# New Orion Context Broker with CORS VM download

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

thanks you for the Orion CB Virtual Machine download availability : (http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/publishsubscribe-context-broker-orion-context-broker/downloads)

But can we ask to have the VM of the new Orion CB (With CORS) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the most recent version (Orion 0.22.0 by the time being, which includes CORS support for GET request) just update the RPM that comes in the VM:

```
sudo yum install contextBroker
```

Then, enable CORS in the /etc/sysconfig/contextBroker file, e.g:

```
BROKER_EXTRA_OPS="-corsOrigin __ALL"
```

and restart the Orion service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/contextBroker restart
```

Comment: Now that's a clear and precise answer that works! Thanks! 

Haven't seen something so easy from Fiware until this :D